# An exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. The directory name is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I've been trying to upload and import csv file into my datatable but it keeps coming out an error. It states that the directory name is invalid.

```
    protected void Upload(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        const string CSV_CONNECTIONSTRING = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"{0}\";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"";

        string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files1/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(csvPath);


        **var AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(csvPath).GetFiles("*csv"); - error here**
```

Comment: what is the value in `csvPath`

Comment: Looks like you're using the path to a _file_ to get all files in a _directory_. That won't work. Use the path to '~/Files1/' in the ```new DirectoryInfo```

Comment: Another error came out.Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\Files1'.

Comment: how do i check the value in the path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files1/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
```

csvPath is file path not directory path.

Make sure there is a folder named "File1" in the project root directory.

and..

```
    string csvPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files1/");
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Path.Combine(csvPath,fileName));
    var AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(csvPath).GetFiles("*csv");
```

Comment: wow thanks^^ however another error came out in a different code.          
string ConStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConStr"].ConnectionString; it says Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: check this...  https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-Get-Connection-String-from-WebConfig-file-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx